# documentation for creation of API s in wso2 ESB 4.2.1 not uptodate

Tags: wso2-esb

I have downloaded the binary zip file from their site and installed wso2 ESB 4.2.1 and wanted to create a API and share it among my co-developers. Please suggest how I should proceed. I was able to do the same in the cloud version but is finding difficulty in doing the same in the product version. I have tried to follow the documentation provided here on https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Creating+APIs but I think that it's not uptodate because I am not finding any match between the product screens and the screens that are provided in the document, specially the Add API page

Answer (score 0):

According to you have downloaded and installed WSO2 ESB 4.2.1 (but website has latest stable version 4.8.1, i am not sure from where you get it). The documentation you are following is the documentation of WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. Better to use WSO2 ESB 4.8.1.